# NordVPN setup on linux

Tags: vpn, openvpn

NordVPN does not offer an automatic setup for linux, just VPN config files. What's the best way to implement this?

(my own implementation below, please feel free to comment or suggest improvements!)

EDIT: When I wrote this, I did not know that NordVPN did introduce a [command line tool for linux](https://support.nordvpn.com/#/Connectivity/Linux/1182453582/Installing-and-using-NordVPN-on-Linux.htm) recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a little script that downloads the config files, renames them and enables automatic authentification. Insert your NordVPN login credentials in the `generate authentification file` part.

```
#!/bin/bash
# run as root!!!

# install openvpn. I'm running arch, this might be different on your system.
pacman -S openvpn

# go to openvpn config folder
cd /etc/openvpn

# download config files, extract and clean up
wget https://downloads.nordcdn.com/configs/archives/servers/ovpn.zip
unzip ovpn.zip
rm ovpn.zip

# rename tcp config files and put them in /etc/openvpn/client
cd ovpn_tcp
for file in *; do mv "${file}" "${file/.nordvpn.com.tcp.ovpn/}tcp.conf"; done
cp * ../client

# rename udp config files and put them in /etc/openvpn/client
cd ../ovpn_udp
for file in *; do mv "${file}" "${file/.nordvpn.com.udp.ovpn/}udp.conf"; done
cp * ../client

# generate authentification file
cd ../client
printf "<your email>\n<your password>" > auth.txt

# make all configs use authentification file
find . -name '*.conf' -exec sed -i -e 's/auth-user-pass/auth-user-pass\ auth.txt/g' {} \;

# clean up
cd ..
rm -r ovpn_tcp/
rm -r ovpn_udp
```

You can now start and stop vpn-connections via e.g.

```
systemctl start openvpn-client@de415tcp.service
```

and

```
systemctl stop openvpn-client@de415tcp.service
```

To automate this, and to connect to the server recommended by NordVPN, I have written two scripts. Make them executable and put them somewhere in your `$PATH`. 
Pass a country code (like `us`, `de` or `uk`) as command line argument to `start-vpn` if you want to choose a specific country. It automatically chooses a `tcp` connection. You can change that to `udp` if you want.

`start-vpn`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

import requests
import os
import time

# you don't necessarily need the following. It's for monitoring via i3blocks.

def notify_i3blocks():
    os.system('pkill -RTMIN+12 i3blocks')


def fork_and_continue_notifying_in_background():
    newpid = os.fork()
    if newpid == 0:  # if this is the child process
        for i in range(60):
            notify_i3blocks()
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    notify_i3blocks()

    # below is what you do need.

    suffix = ''
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        countries = requests.get('https://nordvpn.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=servers_countries').json()
        for country in countries:
            if country["code"].lower() == sys.argv[1].lower():
                suffix = '&filters={"country_id":' + str(country["id"]) + '}'

    result = requests.get('https://nordvpn.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=servers_recommendations' + suffix)
    profile = result.json()[0]['subdomain'] + 'tcp'

    command = 'systemctl start openvpn-client@' + profile + '.service'

    os.system(command)

    # the following is for i3blocks again.        

    fork_and_continue_notifying_in_background()
```

`stop-vpn`

```
#!/bin/bash

function service {
    systemctl |
    grep openvpn |
    grep running |
    head -n1 |
    awk '{print $1;}'
}

while [[ $(service) ]]; do
    systemctl stop $(service)
done

# notify i3blocks
pkill -RTMIN+12 i3blocks
```

For convenience, I have two aliases in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias start-vpn='sudo start-vpn'
alias stop-vpn='sudo stop-vpn'
```

if you do want to monitor it via `i3blocks`, put this in your `i3blocks` config:

```
[vpn]
interval=once
signal=12
```

and this in your i3blocks-scripts-directory (with name `vpn`):

```
#!/bin/bash

function name {
    systemctl |
    grep openvpn |
    grep running |
    head -n1 |
    awk '{print $1;}' |
    cut -d @ -f 2 |
    cut -d . -f 1
}

starting=$(pgrep -f start-vpn) # this might not be the most accurate, but it works for me. Improvement suggestions are welcomed.

if [[ $(name) ]]; then
    echo $(name)
    echo && echo "#00FF00"
else
    if [[ ${starting} ]]; then
        echo starting vpn...
        echo && echo "#FFFF00"
    else
        echo no vpn
        echo && echo "#FF0000"
    fi
fi
```

In order to automatically start and stop vpn when a network interface goes up/down, put the following in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/10-openvpn`.   To activate the feature you need to `enable` and `start` the `NetworkManager-dispatcher.service`. More info [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Network_services_with_NetworkManager_dispatcher).

At my university, I connect to eduroam, which does not allow vpn. That's why I exclude that.

`/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/10-openvpn`

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$2" in
    up)
        if ! nmcli -t connection | grep eduroam | grep wlp3s0 ; then
            start-vpn
        fi
        ;;
    down)
        stop-vpn
        ;;
esac
```

I hope this helps other people who want to use NordVPN on linux. Again, feel free to comment and suggest improvements. 
In particular, I am not sure how much of a security risk it is to have the NordVPN-password written out in plain text in a file.